# Views and Partials for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, koa, marko

My project uses Koa2 with Marko on the front.

I'm looking to avoid repeating layout HTML that's common on every page. Essentially splitting it out into partials and having a "main" partial (with all the common stuff in it!).

I'm from the "Rails world" where we have application-layouts and partials that get loaded for each specific route, rather than repeating layout

Do we have something similar for Node?

Comment: Yup, try looking up tutorials for templating engines in Node.js.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using Marko as the templating engine and was looking for a solution specific to that..

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/koa-marko-example) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [koa-render-view](https://github.com/arshtepe/koa-render-view) for templates render and use for templates ejs(ejs.co) or template from this list https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js